Can you keep money you find on the floor if it's fairly obvious who lost it beyond reasonable doubt?
The question is inspired by Bava Metzia 23, which seems to provide only one exception to the rule: a sign.
I'm sure there are other general exceptions too e.g. two witnesses saw whose pocket the money fell from (I'm guessing CCTV wouldn't be strong enough evidence as with other cases) but still it seems pretty incredible that this would be the actual Halocha.
It's especially curious since there is an actual norm in society to announce and Torah is rarely more lenient than social norms (I'm sure endless counterexamples can be found but I think there is still the general idea that Torah expects us to go above and beyond the bare minimum wrt decent behaviour).

There is a rule of loving your fellow Jew, which means to do with him like you'd like others to do with you. If you know it is his money, you should return it based on this rule.

To help you understand the ruling you must know the difference between de-jure and de-facto loss. Usually, we focus on factual Aveda, but here, the sages proclaim something to be considered (de-jure) lost once it leaves the owner's pocket, even if a person walks behind her and sees the money falling. It's just a matter of legal definition - she just lost ownership of that money. After that ruling, rabbis wonder if the founder can ease the situation and perform other mitzvos, such as loving your fellow, etc.

B"H
The point of the sign is not (only) so YOU can know who it belongs to, it's to establish whether or not the original owner would have given up hope on retrieving the item.
If it has a sign, then (in many cases) the original owner never lost hope that he would get it back. Therefore, since he never relinquished ownership from it, it still belongs to him and one who finds it must return it.
If one lost an object with no recognizable sign on it (also assuming that the original owner didn't know about the witnesses. If he did know, maybe other laws would apply) that means that at the moment the original owner realized the object was lost (with no sign), he gave up hope of retrieving it.
That feeling of giving up hope of retrieving it has legal implications. It means that he relinquished ownership of the item, and it now becomes ownerless.
Reference

If the owner of an item gives up on ever getting it back, that is
considered a forfeiture of the object and it’s permissible to take and
keep it.[44] That can happen in the following ways: The owner says
explicitly that he has given up hope of finding it.[45] This is true
even if the item has simanim.[46] Similarly, if it’s evident that the
object has been lost for a long time such as if one sees moss or rust
on the object, then it’s permissible to take and keep the object.[47]
This is true even if the item has identifying simanim.[48] Also, if an
item without identifying features is lost, a person does not expect to
get it back. When he discovers that it is lost, he will give up on it
and it will automatically be forfeited.[49] This isn't true in a place
where there are talmidei chachamim.[50]


That’s fine. You can still have a situation where someone just put 200 back in their pocket full of hope to have it on them 5 minutes later, especially where they took it specifically to pay this exact amount any minute now. Only instead of putting it in their pocket they dropped it accidentally. A minute later someone right around them picks it up and decides to keep it. You could of course argue - those that really care about their money are going to put signature on every banknote but we know in practice no one does and people do try to look for their lost signless money.

@rudolfovic If all of that information is known to the finder, that's a different situation, which would change the law. If you know that the person who lost the money is unaware of having lost it, this is called יאוש שלא מדעת (Bava Metzia 21b), and is forbidden to take according to Abbaye, whose opinion we follow in this case.
